# Cron jobs not sending mail - Solaris 11

Tags: email, cron

I need some assistance please.

I've written several scripts which runs on a `cron` schedule as **root** in **Solaris 11.3**.  When I run these scripts manually I receive the mailx mails.  But when the scripts are scheduled via `cron` under the **root** user I don't receive any mails.

Below the last system mail sent to root:

```
Final-Recipient: RFC822; user@company.co.za
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 501 5.5.4 Invalid domain name
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 11:43:19 +0200 (SAST)

--u4A9h9nx003306.1462873399/vkbprod.
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <user>
Received: (from root@localhost)
        by vkbprod. (8.15.1+Sun/8.15.1) id u4A9h9nw003306
        for user@company.co.za; Tue, 10 May 2016 11:43:09 +0200 (SAST)
Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 11:43:09 +0200 (SAST)
From: user <user>
Message-Id: <201605100943.u4A9h9nw003306@vkbprod.>
```

Many thanks,
Tewie

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the output of your cron, as it could have error messages related to mailx (Problems with unprintable chars, UTF8 etc). Also keep in mind that in a cron job some env variables are not as they are in an interactive shell!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately the log isn't of much help.

Comment: # tail -20 /var/cron/log
<  sag 13022 c Thu May 12 06:15:00 2016 rc=1
>  CMD: /rscripts/test-mail.bsh
>  root 1916 c Thu May 12 07:15:00 2016
>  CMD: /app1/sag/unix_scripts/sendplog.bsh
>  sag 1917 c Thu May 12 07:15:00 2016
<  root 1916 c Thu May 12 07:15:00 2016 rc=1
<  sag 1917 c Thu May 12 07:15:00 2016 rc=1
>  CMD: /rscripts/test-mail.bsh
>  root 9364 c Thu May 12 08:15:00 2016
>  CMD: /app1/sag/unix_scripts/sendplog.bsh
>  sag 9366 c Thu May 12 08:15:00 2016
<  root 9364 c Thu May 12 08:15:00 2016 rc=1
<  sag 9366 c Thu May 12 08:15:00 2016 rc=1

Comment: It's working on another identical none productive box but for some reason I can't get it working on this one - Have a great one!